# JQuery and Google Maps API issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, object, google-maps-api-3

I'm currently working on a web app that updates a google maps marker every 10 seconds. I am getting the lat long coordinates from a database then loading them into an object like this :

I make the ajax request then

```
var da = JSON.parse(data);
```

then loop through all the results:

```
$.each(da, function(idx, obj) {
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(obj.Lat, obj.Longitude);
  markers[obj] = new google.maps.Marker({position: latLng,map: map});
});
```

But later on in the code i am having a problem trying to do this :

```
markers[obj].setPosition(latLng);
```

It is not moving the marker to the new position, am i missing something?

the 'markers[]' object is declared globally.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: OK i have made an edit, thanks.

Comment: `obj` is only known inside the `each`-callback

Answer (score 2):

Inside the each loop, `markers[obj]` should be `markers[idx]`.

Outside the loop, change

- `markers[obj].setPosition(latLng);`
- to
- `markers[idx].setPosition(latLng);`

assuming you have that line in a second loop and named that loops first parameter `idx` as before

**Your Code**

```
$.each(da, function(idx, obj) {
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(obj.Lat, obj.Longitude);
  markers[obj] = new google.maps.Marker({position: latLng,map: map});
});
```

.....

```
markers[obj].setPosition(latLng);
```

**Suggested Changes**

```
$.each(da, function(idx, obj) {
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(obj.Lat, obj.Longitude);
  markers[idx] = new google.maps.Marker({position: latLng,map: map});
});
```

.....

```
markers[idx].setPosition(latLng);
```

Comment: nice solution, starred for future reference :D

Comment: I sorted it by doing
    markers[obj.Lat]
but your works also, thanks :)